# Redux Framework Extending WP_Customize_Section - How to get the class defined for a section

Tags: wordpress, customization, redux-framework

I'm using redux framework in my theme and I'm customizing my theme by extending the WP_Customize_Section using the file "[customizer_section.php](https://github.com/reduxframework/redux-framework/blob/master/ReduxCore/inc/extensions/customizer/inc/customizer_section.php)"

While Defining my Options, I have defined a section as:

```
Redux::setSection($myTheme_opt_name, array(
'id' => 'my-th-shortcode-subsec-shortcodes-blog-tab',
'title' => __('Blog', 'myTheme'),
'subsection' => true,
'class' => MyCSSClass,
'fields' => array(
    array(
        'subtitle' => __('Controls the color of the icon circle in blog alternate and recent posts layouts.', 'myTheme'),
        'id' => 'my-th_shortcode_blog_icon_circle_color',
        'compiler' => true,
        'type' => 'color',
        'title' => __('Blog Icon Circle Color', 'myTheme'),
        'default' => '#eef0f2',
    ),
),
    )
```

);

in our own customizer_section.php I want to add in the class defined in my options on my own codeblock

```
protected function render_fallback() {
    $classes = 'accordion-section redux-section control-section control-section-' . $this->type;
    ?>
    <li id="accordion-section-<?php echo esc_attr($this->id); ?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr($classes); ?>">
        <h3 class="accordion-section-title" tabindex="0">
            <?php
            echo wp_kses($this->title, array(
                'em' => array(),
                'i' => array(),
                'strong' => array(),
                'span' => array(
                    'class' => array(),
                    'style' => array(),
                ),
            ));
            ?>

        </h3>
```

in the above code in the li tag I want to get the css class (MyCSSClass) which I have defined in my options above. How can I get that css class in here?

Answer (score 0):

ok Figured it out..... I used the code below to get the class of a section and used it in the li class

```
$this->class_name = isset($this->section['class']) ? $this->section['class'] : '';
```